# how to create new user from custom controller in laravel Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am working on custom controller that will allow the admin of the system to create new user

so far i did the below for store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'role' => 'required',
        'department' => 'required',
    ]);
    $user = User::create($validatedData);

    return redirect('add-staff')->with('success', 'User is successfully saved');
}
```

the above function will create new user in users database but i can't login with the new created user and it will show un-hashed password in the databse

is there a way to create new user with jetstream from custom controller?

Comment: But it doesn't make the Jetstream Teams and all that so this whole method is not the proper way I am thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you never hash the password, one way of solving this would be to add before the `User::create` the following line:

```
$validatedData['password'] = Hash::make($validatedData['password']);
```

Comment: But it doesn't make the Jetstream Teams and all that so this whole method is not the proper way I am thinking.